# How can I assign a nested structure using NodeBuilder in Grails in Config.groovy?

Tags: grails, builder

I'm trying to graph a site's structure for navigation using builder syntax inside Config.groovy as follows:

```
com.foo.demo.siteStructure = NodeBuilder.newInstance().site() {
    item(controller: 'sample', action: 'list')
    item(controller: 'address', action: 'list') {
        item(controller: 'city', action: 'list', title: 'Municipality')
    }
}
```

The object this produces in the debugger is:

```
site[attributes={}; value=[item[attributes={controller=sample, action=list}; value=[]], item[attributes={controller=city, action=list, title=Municipality}; value=[]]]]
```

So it appears to be only going one level deep, and replacing the second item with the one it contains.

I get the same single level of nesting if I pre-define an Item object and use `ObjectGraphBuilder`:

```
class Item {
    String controller
    String action
    String title
    SiteNode parent
    List<Item> items = []
}
```

So, it would appear the ConfigSlurper is mangling the result somehow.  Is there a better way to mark up a nested structure as a config value?

Comment: Don't know Grails, but a quick Google search turned up this: http://books.google.com/books?id=vg09ocrbhXoC&pg=PA120&lpg=PA120&dq=nodebuilder+grails&source=bl&ots=nhQvLB2hSy&sig=f85dBhJ93sYqAbtll9ju6rdsdhk&sa=X&ei=288zUPf3EYff0gGctYHQBA&ved=0CCIQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=nodebuilder%20grails&f=false

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did manage to get this working by adapting how the resource plugin reads the configuration. I first changed the configured value to a regular closure:

```
com.foo.demo.siteStructure = {
    root {
        item(controller: 'sample', action: 'list')
        item(controller: 'address', action: 'list') {
            item(controller: 'city', action: 'list', title: 'Municipality')
        }
    }
}
```

Then did the actual processing of the dsl inside a singleton (something like this):

```
Node root
def menus = grailsApplication.config.com.foo.demo.siteStructure
if (menus instanceof Closure) {
    def builder = new NodeBuilder()
    menus.delegate = builder
    menus.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
    root = menus()
}
```